# Terminal calculator like concalc from Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, command-line

Is there a terminal calculator for the Mac that's similar to `concalc` from Ubuntu?

`concalc` allows you to calculate an expression by prefixing it with the tool name (more on the [concalc man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/concalc.1.html))

Expected usage:

```
concalc 2*(3+4/9)^3
```

Comment: If you have a license of MATLAB, you could do much more complex calculations through terminal (although it has a GUI app) 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Mac comes preinstalled with [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html);

```
bc -le "2*(3+4/9)^3"
bc <<< "2*(3+4/9)^3" -l
```

both produce

> 81.73113854595336076784

(thanks @Gilby for the more natural syntax)

The `-l` option is needed to change the precision; without it, it rounds 4/9 down to 0 and the result will be 54 instead.

It also has an interactive mode (`bc -l`) where you can enter expressions in the prompt.

Comment: Thank you, works as expected. Added an alias `alias '?'='bc -le'` to `.zshrc` so I can execute it e.g. `? 2+2` that outputs `4`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Glorfindel’s answer (should be accepted), there is [Calc](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) (free) which is a C style arbitrary precision calculator. I’m just posting this as an excellent alternative to consider.

It’s available via [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/calc/) and [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/calc).  I’ve not used this on a Mac, but in FreeBSD.  What I  liked about it was that you could either use it as a single CLI command or in interactive mode; just type `calc` and begin entering calculations

Calc allows you to use variables and functions in your calculations:

```
% calc "v=2; 5^v"
  25

% calc "v=3; x=v^2; sqrt(x)"
  3

% calc "define myfunc(a,b) = a^b; myfunc(8,2)"
myfunc(a,b) defined
    64
```

Additionally, you can create a file of calculations and have them read into calc with a `calc -f filename` operator.  This is helpful when defining your own complex functions.

Comment: That's a good option, not for my use case, but maybe would help somebody else. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 4):

This answer discusses a few possibilities that are bundled with macOS.

### Shell built-in features

In this section, `$` represents a bash prompt and `%` represents a zsh prompt.

For simple operations, if you don't mind typing a little more punctuation, you can use the shell's built-in arithmetic. The shell evaluates arithmetic expressions inside `$((…))` or `$[…]` (they're exactly equivalent).

```
# bash or zsh
$ echo $[3*4] $((1/2))
12 0
```

[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) can only do integer operations. [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html#Arithmetic-Evaluation) can also do floating point operations.

```
# zsh only
% echo $[1./2]
0.5
```

To set up easier access to arithmetic in zsh without having to type punctuation, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700892/evaluate-terms-in-zsh-without-a-command/700946#700946. (I don't recommend it though: it's a lot of work for little benefit compared to typing a couple of punctuation characters or running zcalc.)

In zsh, you can get additional mathematical functions by loading the [`zsh/mathfunc`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fmathfunc-Module) module.

```
% zmodload zsh/mathfunc
% echo $[sin(1)]
0.8414709848078965
```

And by running [`zmathfunc`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmathfunc), you get access to a few other functions.

```
% autoload -zU zmathfunc
% zmathfunc
% echo $((sum(1,2,3)))
6
```

Zsh also comes with a [calculator mode](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zcalc), which gives access to the same operators and functions, plus a few more features like the constant `PI`, output format customization, and a stack. See the manual for details. In particular, run `zcalc -f` to perform floating-point operations all the time (by default, `/` calculates the integer quotient if both operands are integers).

```
% autoload -zU zcalc
% zcalc
> 3/2
1
> 3/2.
1.5
> sin(PI/2)
1.
> q
% zcalc -f
> 3/2
1.5
```

To make all of this available by default in all interactive shells, make sure you're using zsh and put this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
autoload -zU zmathfunc
zmathfunc
autoload -zU zcalc
```

### bc and dc

[`bc`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bc&apropos=0&sektion=1) and [`dc`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dc&apropos=0&sektion=1) are two classic Unix calculator programs. `bc` uses classical infix notation whereas `dc` uses reverse Polish notation (RPN).

Note that both tools work with a defined number of digits (called the *scale*) after the decimal point, rather than floating point. The default scale is 0.

```
% bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
5/3
1
scale=4
5/3
1.6666
quit
```

(In the session above, the bold text is what I typed, and the rest is displayed by the `bc`, or by the shell on the first line.)

The command to exit `bc` is `quit`. The command to exit `dc` is `q` (`quit` also works). You can also type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> at the beginning of a line.

### Python

Python comes bundled with the system and can offer a very powerful calculator-like experience. [Basic arithmetic operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) are available out of the box. Common mathematical functions are in the [`math` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), and some basic statistical functions in the [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html). There's also [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) for complex numbers, [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) for rational numbers, and [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for decimal arithmetic (rather than binary floating-point).

```
% python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:53)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from math import *
>>> 3//2
1
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> sin(pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
>>> exit()
```

The command to exit Python is `exit()`. You can also type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile `concalc` for macOS yourself.

- Get Homebrew and use it to install `cmake`
- Get the latest `concalc` source from Sourceforge ([version 0.9.3 dated 2010-04-05)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/extcalc-linux/files/extcalc-linux/0.9.3/)
- `tar xzf concalc-0.9.3.tar.gz` to unpack it
- `cd concalc-0.9.3`
- `cmake .` to build the Makefile (ignore the warnings)
- `make`, again ignore the warnings.

This will build `concalc` into the current directory.

```
$ ./concalc -v

Version: 0.9.3 2010-04-04
Calculator algorithms: extcalc v0.9.3 2010-03-28

Author:
Rainer Strobel
http://extcalc-linux.sourceforge.net
2010
$ ./concalc 2*(3+4/9)^3
81.7311385459534
```

Comment: Thank you, that's also a very good option :)